# docker swarm restart 'any' meaning

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

The default restart policy in docker swarm is 'any' but its meaning is not documented in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy). Can someone please clarify the behaviour of 'any'?

Comment: i think this is already asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564483/9279181

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between docker restart\_policy on-failure vs any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554029/whats-the-difference-between-docker-restart-policy-on-failure-vs-any)